# TPicture from MyBase Xml file

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Using Delphi 10.2 I right-click on a TClientDataSet and choose 'Save to MyBase Xml UTF-8 table.' I now have an XML file with this format:

```
<ROW NAME="Angel Fish" SIZE="2" WEIGHT="2" AREA="Computer Aquariums" BMP="AQAAAfY+AABCTfY+AAAAAAAAdgAAACgAAADIAAAAoAAAAAEA ...
```

The BMP field is defined as:

```
<FIELD attrname="BMP" fieldtype="bin.hex" SUBTYPE="TypedBinary" WIDTH="1"/>
```

I'm trying to convert what I believe to be a Base64 string representation of a binary bitmap file into a picture. So far I've got this:

```
uses 
  XMLDoc, Vcl.ComCtrls, XMLIntf, IdCoder, IdCoderMIME, IdGlobal,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Doc:TXMLDocument;
First:IXMLNode;
Str:String;
Bytes: TIdBytes;
Pic:TPicture;
Stream:TMemoryStream;
Writer: TBinaryWriter;

begin
Doc:=TXMLDocument.Create(Self);
Doc.FileName:='D:\temp\ClientDataSet2.xml';
Doc.Active:=true;

First:=Doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes['ROWDATA'].ChildNodes.First;
Str:=First.Attributes['BMP'];

Bytes:=TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeBytes(Str);
Stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
Writer:=TBinaryWriter.Create(Stream);

Writer.Write(TBytes(Bytes));
Stream.Position:=0;

Pic:=TPicture.Create;
Pic.LoadFromStream(Stream);

Image1.Picture:=Pic;

RichEdit1.Text:=Str;
end;
```

However, TPicture.LoadFromStream throws this exception:

First chance exception at $74DCCBB2. Exception class EInvalidGraphic with message 'Unsupported stream format'.

Could anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you reading the raw XML and not just loading it back into a TClientDataset and accessing it through the TField?

Comment: Because I want to reuse this XML file in C#, which I can do minus the image. Having not been able to import the image in C# I thought I'd go back to Delphi to work out the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base64 string you showed decodes to binary data that begins with 8 bytes (`0x01 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xF6 0x3E 0x00 0x00`) before the actual BMP data (`0x42 0x4D ...`) . The `subtype` of the `BMP` attribute is `TypedBinary`, so this is likely some kind of  metadata header to indicate the data is a BMP image. You need to omit those beginning bytes before loading the stream data into `TPicture`.

BTW, `TPicture.LoadFromStream()` just calls `TPicture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream()`, so you should replace `TPicture` with `TBitmap` instead:

```
Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
try
  Bmp.LoadFromStream(Stream); 
  Image1.Picture.Assign(Bmp);
finally
  Bmp.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I'm supposed to avoid saying thank you, but thank you anyhow, that was the solution.